# Find all components with type in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble finding components by type using `scryRenderedComponentsWithType`

code:

```
describe('Layout', function() {
    it('test', function(done) {
        var Wrapper = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return <div className="testWrapper">Hello <span>Jim<div>hi<ul><li><div><span></span></div></li></ul></div></span></div>;
            }
        });

        var TestWrap = React.createClass({
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <p>Test this </p>
                        <Wrapper />
                    </div>
                );
            }
        })

        var renderedTree = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<TestWrap />);
        var renderedMyComponent = TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(renderedTree, 'Wrapper');
        console.log(renderedMyComponent.length);
        done();
    });
});
```

the output of this test returns an array length of `0`. I think I maybe using the function incorrectly but I am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: have you tried changing the string 'Wrapper' to the component <Wrapper />?? or `Wrapper`?

Comment: @Taysky `Wrapper` worked! Will accept answer if you write one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(renderedTree, {function})`

This requires that the second argument be a function, not a string.

Hence, your variable `Wrapper` will work, but not the string `"Wrapper"`.